# AspectJ advice not being executed through unit test

Tags: java, spring, maven, aspectj

I'm stumped.  I'm trying to test an AspectJ class.  My Aspect class gets picked up perfectly when I'm running my application.  However, I seem to be unable to get any Aspect class to intercept any method within a test.

I am using Spring 3.2.2, AspectJ 1.7.2 and Maven 4.

Here is the simple test I'm working with:

The Test AspectJ class

```
package my.package.path.config;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Aspect
public class TestAOP {
    private String message;

    public TestAOP() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* my.package.path.TestAOPClient.relayMessage(..))")
    public void aopPointcut() {
    }

    @Around("aopPointcut()")
    public String monitor(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        String msg = (String)pjp.proceed();
        this.setMessage(msg);
        return msg;
    }
```

}

The class whose method is being intercepted

```
package my.package.path.config;

public class TestAOPClient {
    public String relayMessage(String msg) {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

The Test Class

```
package my.package.path.config;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("src/main/java")
public class AopConfigTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

     @Bean
     public TestAOP testAop() throws Exception {
        return new TestAOP();
     }

     @Test
     public void assertTestConfigIsActive() {
        TestAOPClient client = new TestAOPClient();
        client.relayMessage("hello");
        assertThat(((TestAOP)applicationContext.getBean("testAop")).getMessage(), equalTo("hello"));

    }
}
```

The WebConfig file

```
package my.package.path.web.context;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=false)
@ComponentScan(value={"my.package.path.config", "my.package.path.web"})
public class WebConfig {

}
```

Invariably, I will get the assertion error

```
 Expected: "hello" but: was null
```

My WebApplicationContext seems to be picked up, since at runtime, I will get an ApplicationContext failed to load error if I specify a class that does not exist for my Aspect pointcut.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is kind of strange that you are using your unit test also as a `@Configuration` source.

You should remove the `@Configuration` annotation from the unit test and move the `testAOP()` bean definition to `WebConfig`. But most importantly the bean being advised **must not be created manually, but by Spring**:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration("src/main/java")
public class AopConfigTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

     @Autowired
     private TestAOP testAop;

     @Autowired
     private TestAOPClient client;

     @Test
     public void assertTestConfigIsActive() {
        client.relayMessage("hello");
        assertThat(((TestAOP)applicationContext.getBean("testAop")).getMessage(), 
            equalTo("hello"));
    }

}
```

Updated config with the bean definition:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=false)
@ComponentScan(value={"my.package.path.config", "my.package.path.web"})
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public TestAOP testAop() throws Exception {
        return new TestAOP();
    }

    @Bean
    public TestAOPClient testAopClient() throws Exception {
        return new TestAOPClient();
    }

}
```

If your target was to test whether the AOP configuration works and `TestAOP` is really a testing bean (not just a dummy name for this question), you can create a special `TestConfig` configuration class, move the bean definition there and use it from the test `@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebConfig.class,TestConfig.class})`.

Comment: I moved things around as you suggested.  It does look cleaner.  But it still does not work.  Right now, I have everything but my test classes in the src/main/java area of the code, while the Test class itself is in src/test/java.  TestAOP is annotated in WebConfig.

Could it be something related to when and how weaving occurs when the test are run?  Is there a configuration I need to set somewhere to have it happen? I'm very new to Spring.

Comment: Oh my, just noticed that you are creating the target bean manually in the test `TestAOPClient client = new TestAOPClient();`... it does not work this way. Spring must be the one who is creating the bean! I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointcut configuration is wrong (package should be my.package.path.config to match your test client)

```
@Pointcut("execution(* my.package.path.TestAOPClient.relayMessage(..))")
```

and your client is

```
package my.package.path.config;

public class TestAOPClient {
...
```

change it to this

```
@Pointcut("execution(* my.package.path.config.TestAOPClient.relayMessage(..))")
```

should work.

Comment: That's a typo from when I changed my package name in order to not expose the name of the company.  I reviewed the packages and they are correct..

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I had a similar issue to that of @Emilie, and my `@Pointcut` expression was the final issue preventing my `@Before` advice from running!